# jsplumb: Creating two connections from the same source anchor

Tags: jsplumb

I'm having a hell of a time with jsPlumb trying to create two connections from the same source anchor.

For example, in the JSFiddle below I'm trying to create two connections from the block 1 anchor to the two other blocks 2 and 3. 
http://jsfiddle.net/dutchman71/TYerW/3/

For some reason it works fine in the jsPlumb example here with the green dot anchors.
http://jsplumb.org/jquery/draggableConnectorsDemo.html#

Can anyone tell my what I'm missing?

```
            var endpointOptions = { 
                    anchor:"BottomCenter",
                    maxConnections:-1, 
                    isSource:true, 
                    isTarget:true, 
                    endpoint:["Dot", {radius:6}], 
                    setDragAllowedWhenFull:true,
                    paintStyle:{fillStyle:"#5b9ada"},
                    connectorStyle : {  lineWidth: 4, strokeStyle:"#5b9ada" },
                    connector:[ "Bezier", { curviness:1 }],
                    connectorOverlays:[ 
                        [ "Arrow", { width:15, length:15, location:1, id:"arrow" } ], 
                        [ "Label", { label:"", id:"label" } ]
                    ]               
                    }

            jsPlumb.bind("ready", function() {

                    jsPlumb.addEndpoint('block1', endpointOptions);

                    jsPlumb.addEndpoint('block2', endpointOptions);

                    jsPlumb.addEndpoint('block3', endpointOptions);

                    jsPlumb.draggable('block1');
                    jsPlumb.draggable('block2');
                    jsPlumb.draggable('block3');
            });
```

Answer (score 1):

A nice guy on Google groups helped me out on this one: the jsPlumb version I included from another sample is obsolete. If I include this one http://jsplumb.org/js/jquery.jsPlumb-1.3.16-all-min.js is works fine.

Comment: Thank you for giving the answer on this one, had me stuck too.

Answer (score 0):

set maxconnections to a positive integer. that should do it.

and maybe you should make your endpoints bigger and give the connector lines a smallr z-index, than the enpoints, so you won't missclick on the canvas instead of the div
(the canvas blocks almost the whole div on Block 1 after a connection is established to Block 2 check it in your element inspector/firebug/etc)

Answer (score 0):

Change the radius of the endPoint to endpoint

["Dot", {radius:1}],

and connectorStyle's line width to 1

connectorStyle : {  lineWidth: 4, strokeStyle:"#5b9ada" }